# How to delete GlassFish Server ?

Tags: delete, glassfish

I need to delete glassfish server on ubuntu.

I didn't find uninstall file, how can I delete glassfish ?

Comment: Where did your `uninstall.sh` file gone?

Comment: Check in the glass server directory to see if you have an `uninstall` file else do what karel post as an anwer

Comment: @Arun I didn't find unistall.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation location of GlassFish is `/opt/glassfish4` or `/opt/glassfish5` depending on the version. Run the following command:

```
sudo rm -R /opt/glassfish4
```

Comment: I guess, auto-remove instead of remove but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Glassfish files in /opt/glassfish4 and When I runned this query, taken this error 'dpkg-query: package 'glassfish(3,4,5)' is not installed 
'

Comment: I am looking for this file in my file manager but I can not find it

Comment: Well, Is now completely deleted ?

Comment: That will completely delete it, except for a hidden folder named .glassfish in your user's home directory which you can optionally delete too.